# How to write an enumeration on one line with erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I normally write enumerations in html and erb in multiple lines e.g.

```
  <% @results.each do  |str| %>
      <%= str %><br>
  <% end -%>
```

but it would be nice to do in one line, something like:

```
<%= @results.each  { |str| "#{str}<br>" }
```

but that particular way clearly does not work. How do you do it?  In the particular case I am looking at, each `str` includes a `\n` at the end of it. But I am interested in the either case i.e. with each `str` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```rb
@results = ["foo\n", "bar\n"]
```

Then:

```rb
<%= (@results.map  { |s| s.gsub('\n','') }.join('<br>') + "<br>").html_safe %>
```